# Definition of Corrected Contingency Coefficient

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, covariance, definition

I quote *RACHEV, HÖCHSTÖTTER, FABOZZI, FOCARDI (2010)*.

Starting from the bivariate variable $(x,y)$, with the component variable $x$ taking values in $(v_i, i=1,\dots,r)$ and the component variable $y$ taking values in $(w_j, j=1,\dots,s)$, one can define the **chi-square test statistic** as:
\begin{equation}
\chi^2=n\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^s\frac{\left(f_{x,y}\left(v_i, w_j\right)-f_x\left(v_i\right)f_y\left(w_j\right)\right)^2}{f_x\left(v_i\right)f_y\left(w_j\right)}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $f_{x,y}$ denoting the relative frequency of the bivariate variable $(x,y)$, $f_x$ denoting the relative frequency of the variable $x$ and $f_y$ denoting the relative frequency of the variable $y$.

One problem arises with $\chi^2$ as to its dependence on the data size $n$. For increasing $n$, the statistic can grow beyond any bound such that there is no theoretical maximum. The solution to this problem is given by the so-called **Pearson contingency coefficient** (or simply *contingency coefficient*) defined by:
\begin{equation}
C=\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{\chi^2+n}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Clearly, $C$ is such that $0\leq C< 1$. Consequently, it assumes values which are strictly less than one but may become arbitrarily close to one. $\color{red}{\textrm{This is still not satisfactory enough for our purpose to design a measure that can}}$ $\color{red}{\textrm{uniquely determine}}$ $\color{red}{\textrm{the respective degrees of dependence of different data sets.}}$

There is another coefficient that can be based on the following. In the extreme case of total dependence of $x$ and $y$, each variable will assume a certain value if and only if the other variable assumes a particular corresponding value. Hence, we have $k=\min\left\{r,s\right\}$ unique pairs that occur with positive frequency. $\color{red}{\textrm{Then one can show that:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{C=\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}\tag{3}}
\end{equation}
such that, generally, $0\leq C\leq \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}<1$. $\color{red}{\textrm{Now, the standardized coefficient can be given by:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{C_{\text{corr}}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}C\tag{4}}
\end{equation}
which is called the **corrected contingency coefficient** with $0\leq C\leq 1$.

---

---

Could you please help me understand the $\color{red}{\textrm{three parts in red above?}}$. In general, which is the "aim" pursued in passing from $(2)$ to $\color{red}{(4)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pearson contingency coefficient is intended to provide us some measure regarding the dependence between data columns (which sometimes, when discussing regression, we call collinearity). $C$ takes values in $[0,1)$ when values near 0 indicate column independence, values far from 0 indicate dependence. But how far is far? Can we achieve a tighter upper bound? That's the general idea.

Red part (a): notice the term "degrees of dependence". If there are zero of them, columns are independent.

Red part (c): as the upper bound for $C$ was found, dividing by this bound (/multiplying by its reciprocal) $C_{corr}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}C$ yields $0\le C_{corr} \le 1$.

Red part (b): Let $k=\min\{r,s\}$ and assume the extreme condition described (e.g. $x,y$ is a pair of letter and digit. Although there are 10 digits and 26 letters, The only pairs which appear are $(a,0), (s,1), (h,2), (i,3), (r,4), (g,5), (u,6), (n,7), (y,8), (t,9)$). Each of the $k=10$ possible pairs has relative frequency $f_{xy}$, as well as each of the components (i.e each letter and digit have frequencies $f_x,f_y$).

For letters outside the $k$ used above, $f_x=0$ and obviously $f_{xy}=0$ so they're not summed. Our sum is now:
$$\chi^2=n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{(f_{x,y}(v_i, w_j)-f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j))^2}{f_x\left(v_i\right)f_y(w_j)}\\=n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[\frac{f^2_{xy}(v_i,w_j)}{f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)}\right]-2n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[f_{xy}(v_i,w_j)\right]+n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)\right]$$

The rightmost sum equals 1 as well as the middle sum (second probability axiom), so we only need to solve

$$\chi^2=n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[\frac{f^2_{xy}(v_i,w_j)}{f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)}\right]-2n+n=n\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[\frac{f^2_{xy}(v_i,w_j)}{f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)}\right]-n$$

If the pair $(v_i,w_j)$ does not appear on our list, $f_{xy}(v_i,w_j)=0$ is not summed. The pair matching is one-to-one (a digit always appears with the same letter and vice versa), so now assume that a pair $(v_i,w_j)$ does exist. In fact, it appears $a$ times (out of $n$), so its relative pair frequency is $f_{xy}(v_i,w_j)=\frac{a}{n}$. However, these are also the only $a$ occurrences of $v_i$ and $w_j$ so $f_x(v_i)=f_y(w_j)=f_{xy}(v_i,w_j)=\frac{a}{n}$. This means that when a pair does exist, the fraction equals $1$. We have $k$ such cases, so overall
$$\chi^2=nk-n=n(k-1)$$

Now getting the boundary for $C$ is easy:

$$C=\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{\chi^2+n}}=\sqrt{\frac{n(k-1)}{n(k-1)+n}}=\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}} \qquad\blacksquare.$$

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. Just three questions: 

**1)** Above, you meant "The rightmost sum equals 1" (instead of "The leftmost sum equals 1"), didn't you? 

**2)** I cannot see why $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)\right]$ can be proven to be equal to $1$ thanks to the second probability axiom. Could you please give me an insight? **3)** Why does $C_{\text{corr}}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}C$ yield that $0\leq C_{\text{corr}}\leq1$?

Comment: **1)** Thanks, corrected it. **2)** The sum of $f_y(w_j)$ over all $j$ values is 1. That's the axiom. The sum $\sum_{j=1}^{k}{f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)}$ is thus $f_x(v_i)$. The sum of $f_x(v_i)$ over all $i$ values is 1. That's the axiom again. We therefore get that $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\left[f_x(v_i)f_y(w_j)\right]=1$. That's (also) the 2D integral for the product of 2 marginal PDFs (which is the axiom once again). **3)** If $\max(C)=\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}$ then $\max(C_{corr})=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}\cdot\max(C)=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}=1$.